# Understanding 'potential null dereference' when dealing with NSError

Tags: objective-c, nserror

I understand that this may seems a very basic question, but I always thought that explaining (and understanding) basic question is the key to build clean and working code. 
I have the following fragment of code in a CoreData entity:

```
-(BOOL)validateForInsert:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error {
    [super validateForInsert:error];
    return [self validateInternal:error];
}

-(BOOL)validateInternal:(NSError *__autoreleasing *)error {
  // checking attributes and build userInfo error
  if(anyErrors) {
    *error = [NSError errorWithDomain:appDomain code:200 userInfo:details];
    return NO;
  }
  return YES;
}
```

by running 'analyze' in Xcode I get the famous 'potential null dereference' when creating error. While the compiler is not giving any alert, and the code has always worked.
This could be a question too, why the compiler doesn't warn me about that ?

But coming to the code, I perfectly know the solution, which is to check if (error != nil), but I am quite lost at this.
The question start at the beginning, at the meaning of NSError *_autoreleasing* , why the surrounding star ? Which should be a pointer to a pointer ?

Supposing I would like to call the validateForInsert: by myself, how can I build an *_autoreleasing* object ?

The following question, I suppose is related to the question above: if I am building the *error from scratch, why am I suppose to check if nil first ?

Last but not least, the code works fine, the errors get intercepted, could you please spot a case that can have it fail or crash ? As I said I am using CoreData, a generic example would be fine, but another related to CoreData is appreciated.

thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
*error = [NSError errorWithDomain:appDomain code:200 userInfo:details];
```

is syntactically correct, therefore the compiler does not warn. The Analyzer detects that this will crash at runtime if `error = NULL`, i.e. if you call

```
[myObj validateForInsert:NULL];
```

If you call

```
NSError *error;
[myObj validateForInsert:&error];
```

then you pass the address of `error`, therefore you pass a variable of type `NSError * *`.

The `__autoreleasing` modifier is a hint to the ARC compiler that the object assigned to `error` is an autoreleased object.

You can declare a variable to be autoreleasing with

```
NSError * __autoreleasing error;
[myObj validateForInsert:&error];
```

but normally you do not care. ARC just generates the correct code.

For details, read the [Transitioning to ARC Release Notes](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#releasenotes/ObjectiveC/RN-TransitioningToARC/Introduction/Introduction.html). There are also lots of answers on this topic on stackoverflow.

Comment: I completely missing the meaning of autoreleasing, I thought of it as a variable name !! Thanks for the explanation, for me it is quite enough to mark as answered.